# How to set the type for useAppDispatch when passed as props from a nx app to a nx library?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, types, monorepo

I am trying to create a generic login component in a shared nx library where I have some redux-toolkit slice logic being associated with it.
In order to not create a store on the  shared library, I imported the slice from the shared library to the nx app and created a store like this:

**Store.ts**

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { reducer as authReducer } from './slices/auth';

import { loginReducer } from '@shared-ui';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    login: loginReducer,
  },
});

// Infer the `RootState` and `AppDispatch` types from the store itself
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export type Thunk = ThunkAction<Promise<unknown>, RootState, unknown, Action<unknown>>;
export default store;
```

Now, in order to feed this slice to my shared library I did something like this:

**Login.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector, RootState } from 'store';

import { LoginForm } from '@shared-ui';

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const logindata = useCustomSelector((state: RootState) => state.login);

  return (
        <LoginForm
          useDispatch={AppDispatch}
          logindata={logindata}
        />
  );
};
```

Now, this seems a bit antipattern as I never passed down the slice data like this. However, I didnt want the shared login component to access the global store and wanted to keep it seperate which is why I did it this way. If anyone has a better idea please suggest.

But with this approach when I am trying to set the types for Login component like this, I dont want to set the type for useDispatch to be `any`. What should the type be here considering I dont want to access the app's AppDispatch type.

**Login.tsx**

```
type LoginProps = {
  useDispatch: any
  logindata: LoginSliceData,
};

const Login = ({ useDispatch, logindata }: LoginProps) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
```

If anyone needs further clarification, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `hooks.ts` file:

```
import { TypedUseSelectorHook, useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

// Use throughout your app instead of plain `useDispatch` and `useSelector`
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector
```

And then import `{useAppDispatch, useAppSelector}` from there.

Then you can use:
`const logindata = useAppSelector((state) => state.login);`

At that point, there shouldn't be any need to have `useDispatch` as a prop, just use:
`const dispatch = useAppDispatch()` and continue from there.

Source: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript